# Is a SQL Keylookup always a bad thing to be optimized?

Tags: sql, optimization

In an effort to optimize our application, I'm running the app with SQL profiler and examining any queries which have extensive reads, cpu time, then diving deeper looking at execution plans of specific queries.

One aspect of the execution plans that I've seen are key lookups.  In one specific query, the key lookup is 98% of the of the cost of the query.

However, is that always bad, and should the number of rows/cpu cost be the deciding factor on whether or not to create an index which includes those keys?

In this specific example, we're looking up a customer by last name (which is index), and returning properties of the customer such as first name, address, city, etc.  The index does not include those extra properties, so a key lookup is executed.

BUT, the customer base is smallish, and we're only talking about 50 or so rows when finding a customer with the most common last name.  So is it worth it to create an entirely new index when the result set is so small?

Comment: which sql database?

Comment: did you use the index in the query?

Comment: Sorry, MS Sql 2012+.  Yes, I have an index with last name, but the index doesn't include the output columns of first name, address, city, etc.